# Regex to match word including the surrounding square brackets

Tags: .net, regex

In the following text, I want to match only the first [ID], but not the second [ID] which is part of [SOMETHING].[ID]
edit: the actual text does include the square brackets. I need to match the surrounding brackets as well.

> match [ID] but don't match [SOMETHING].[ID]

I used the following regex, but it doesn't match anything.

```
\b\[ID\]
```

why is this regex not working and what's the correct one?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have delimiters on your regex?

Comment: The actual text includes the brackets. I need to match the surrounding brackets as well.

Comment: Do you mean capture and match?  .*\b(\[ID\])\b.*  You have to 'match' the whole line, but capture only what you want..

Comment: @EdH it's not working.. I think the bracket has something to do with it.

Comment: we are all giving you pcre examples (Perl regular expressions) and you have .net noted here... I would google the differences

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483341/regex-to-match-a-substring-within-2-brackets-e-g-i-want-this-text-but-leave?rq=1

Comment: What about this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854973/extracting-tokens-from-a-string-with-regular-expressions-in-net.

Comment: EdH AMissico Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex meets my requirements.

> (?<=\s+|^)\[ID\]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, `\b` doesn't match the beginning of a string. Try:

```
(^|[\W])\[ID\]
```

as your regex instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tested it on http://regexpal.com/ but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: No. I think the brackets have something to do with it because when I'm matching words not withing the brackets, such as (^|\b)someword, it works. but (^|\b)\\[ID\\] doesn't work. what gives?

Comment: Actually, it might not be the brackets. This gives what I think is the effect you want: (^|[\W])\[ID\]

Comment: (^|[\W])\\[ID\\] matches both [ID] and [SOMETHING].[ID] . It should only match [ID]. thanks for your help. I think I found the solution